# Porque no veo las rutas nuevas creadas en laravel?

Tags: php

He creado dos rutas en laravel, cada una tiene su modelo y controlador. Yo guardo los cambios pero reviso en la consola las rutas que tengo y no salen las dos ultimas que he creado. En git veo que si están creadas, en mi archivo local están ahí. No se porque no encuentra la las rutas. Además pruebo las demás rutas en el postman y todo sale bien.

Quien pueda ayudarme se los agradezco.

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor, además recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Prueba limpiar el cache de la ruta con el siguiente comando: php artisan route:cache